# Select text that is not in the options using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html code,

```
<select name="sup" class='form-control' required >
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
</select>
```

Is it possible to display text to the dropdown that is not in the options using JQuery?

More explanation,

I have only option that value is 1 with name of "Value 1".
I want to display "Value 2" with value of 2.
But if I will click the dropdown arrow, It will display only one option, the "Value 1".

Is it possible?

Comment: Are you looking for something more like a placeholder?

Comment: What does "*I want to display "Value 2" with value of 2.*" mean?

Comment: I mean is , i want to select value 2 that is not in the options :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this code for a placeholder could help you, it will show as default value in the select, but will not be selectable, and the user will be forced by html validation to select another option (if you use HTML validation). If you don't use HTML (or other) validation, because the option is disabled, it won't be sent with the form even if it has a value.

The "Other" option will trigger a new input to have a custom response.

```js
//Detects the change of value of the select element.
$("select[name='sup']").change(function() {
 //Checks if the current value of the elemnent is "other"
  if ($(this).val() == "other") {
  //If so, the other input is shown
    $("input[name='other-input']").show();
  } else {
  //else, the input is cleaned and hidden
    $("input[name='other-input']").val("");
    $("input[name='other-input']").hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="sup" class='form-control' required>
<option value="" selected disabled>Placeholder Text</option>
  <option value="1">Value 1</option>
  <option value="2">Value 2</option>
  <option value="3">Value 3</option>
  <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
<input style="display: none; width: 300px;" type="text" name="other-input" placeholder="Type here your custom response">
```

Comment: Technically, of course, the option is shown in the list as well, which the OP said they didn't want. But I don't think it's possible to get closer to the *spirit* of what they wanted than this, without doing a fair bit of coding.

Comment: Exactly what i was thinking, maybe something like a `<label>` placed in front in a very dirty way could get closer to what he wants, but I don't think he has requirements that harsh :D

Comment: What will be the nice way for this,

Comment: I have list of values that will be put on a dropdown, but if the user need to insert new data that not in the list? what will be the nice way for that?

Comment: So you want an option in the dropdown that can be **edited** by the user?

Comment: Yes. but If the user click the dropdown. only one option :)

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you mean, would something like this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bgorxkh4/) suit your needs?

Comment: That will do RDardelet. It doesn't answer my question above but you gave me another way. Thanks. Can I select this as an answer? :)

Comment: I have edited my answer with what was in the fiddle, so you can now select the answer as the correct one.. Happy I helped you

Answer (score 3):

No. What shows when the drop-down isn't open must be one of the options in the select's options. To do something else, you'd have to start playing with overlaying things on top of the select, with all the cross-browser pain that comes with it.

Comment: I selected the answer above because he help me in other way. But 1+ to you.